# how to set horizontal scroll for div such that when adding items by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending check-boxes in a div by jQuery. Div is scroll when overflow. But I see that when checkbox names are large then div does not horizontally scroll but extra content goes to next line while vertical scroll works fine . below is some code

below is code of div creation

```
  <div id="legendBox" style="overflow:scroll;width:145px;height:300px;"></div>
```

This code is to add check boxes in DIV

```
if (legendChecked == "T")
                {
                    legendtest = "<input type='checkbox' class='" + legendClass + "' name='" + legendName + "' style='background-color:" + legendColor + "' value='" + legendName + "' checked onClick=legendChanged();  title='" + legendName + "' />" + legendName;
                } else
                {
                    legendtest = "<input type='checkbox' class='" + legendClass + "' name='" + legendName + "' style='background-color:" + legendColor + "' value='" + legendName + "' onClick=legendChanged();  title='" + legendName + "' />" + legendName;
                }
                $("#legendBox").append(legendtest+"</br>");
```

Please tell me where is mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Or add `display:inline`: http://jsfiddle.net/eq3r9/

**Edit:**
This is a better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eq3r9/1/

Comment: check the second fiddle by placing <br> after each check box and placing a space in lagend name, then reduce the display area such that horizontal scroll show. You will see that legend name after space goes to next line

Comment: Not sure if I totally get what you mean, but: [http://jsfiddle.net/eq3r9/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/eq3r9/2/)